# Connect 500 Error at MongooseError.CastError

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's the deal: I have a form in AngularJS/Node.JS which pulls form questions from a MongoDB and assigns values to each of the answers. I killed my MongoDB database last night. Luckily, I had the JSON files still available.  Created two new collections (same name as previous database) with the JSON files, but I now I get this error when trying to complete the form and post the data back into the database object with the array called answers:

```
Error
     at MongooseError.CastError ((HIDDEN)/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:18:16)
     at ObjectId.cast ((HIDDEN)/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:134:13)
     at Array.MongooseArray.mixin._cast ((HIDDEN)/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:117:32)
     at Array.MongooseArray.mixin._mapCast ((HIDDEN)/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:278:17)
     at Object.map (native)
     at Array.MongooseArray.mixin.push ((HIDDEN)/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:291:25)
     at (HIDDEN)/controllers/user.js:236:22
     at (HIDDEN)/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:187:20
     at (HIDDEN)/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:239:13
     at _arrayEach ((HIDDEN)/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:91:13)
     at _each ((HIDDEN)/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:82:13)
     at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf ((HIDDEN)/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:238:9)
     at Object.async.forEach.async.each ((HIDDEN)/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:215:22)
     at exports.postWizard ((HIDDEN)/controllers/user.js:233:11)
     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] ((HIDDEN)/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
     at next ((HIDDEN)/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
POST /wizard 500 234.552 ms - -
```

Comment: I think I have to create _id for each of my subdocuments. Is there any way to automate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by generating ids for nested objects. I had to db insert each document. MongoDB doesn't automatically generate ID for nested objects; thus, I had to use ObjectId() :

```
 db.questions.insert({ 
    "question": "q1",
    "order": 1,
    "type": "assessment",
    "answers": [{
        "_id" : ObjectId(),
        "answer": "Yes",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "_id" : ObjectId(),
        "answer": "No",
        "value": 0
 }]})
```